# slapd with back_sock does not create a socket

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have installed slapd on Ubuntu 12.04 and configured it with the following under /etc/ldap/slapd.conf:

```
modulepath /usr/lib/ldap
moduleload back_sock.la
database sock
socketpath /tmp/slapd.sock
```

However, if I start slapd with `service slapd restart` then, slapd is running but there is no socket file in /tmp. What am I missing?

**Update:**
Output of `netstat -nlp | grep slapd` is:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:389             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      860/slapd       
tcp6       0      0 :::389                  :::*                    LISTEN      860/slapd       
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8303     860/slapd           /var/run/slapd/ldapi
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you share the output of `sudo netstat -nlp | grep slapd`? Please *edit* your question for this.

Comment: is app armour running ?

Comment: Do you see any slapd-related messages in /var/log/syslog during start/restart?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `back_sock` is to connect to an another socket that already exists. It's documented in the `slapd-sock(5)` manpage. It certainly does not create any socket.

If you review your logs, you'll only see errors when an action is attempted, because the sock backend opens the socket each time it needs to do some action, and closes it afterwards. You'll see an entry `could not open socket` in your logs if the socket cannot be opened for each action.

If you're trying to make slapd listen on a socket instead, you need to modify `/etc/default/slapd`, and adjust/add the slapi:// URL (remember you'll need to encode slashes as %2f, see `slapd(8)` for more details).